# Will windows be open after restart?

Tags: macbook-pro

I restarted my MacBook and I had some important tabs open in Incognito mode. Will they still be open when I reboot?

Answer (score 1):

So you mean browser tabs rather than application windows? **Answer is no**. That's the purpose of private mode / incognito tabs. Once closed - they are gone.

If you talk about opened programs, that is possible.

[image]